# Python3 Concatenate multiple files and ignore header & trailer records

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix

I want to concatenate multiple files and skip the header and trailer records in all the files and have the **column names(always in the 2nd line of the file) occur only once** in the final file while concatenating.

I am able to concatenate,but how do i skip the header,trailer and retain the column names only once?Each file has about 25 million records.

```
 File1.txt

    H,ABC,file1.txt
    Name,address,zipcode
    Rick,ABC,123
    Tom,XYZ,456
    T,2  -----------------record count

 File2.txt

    H,ABC,file2.txt
    Name,address,zipcode
    Jerry,ABC,123
    T,1


 File3.txt

    H,ABC,file3.txt
    Name,address,zipcode
    John,ABC,123
    Mike,XYZ,456
    T,2

 ***Final Output:***

    Name,address,zipcode
    Rick,ABC,123
    Tom,XYZ,456
    Jerry,ABC,123
    Harry,XYZ,456
    John,ABC,123
    Mike,XYZ,456
```

Code:

```
filenames = ['File1.txt', 'File2.txt', 'file3.txt']
with open('output_file', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Given the size of the files, have you considered storing the data into a proper database?  Even something as simple as SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using Python:

Here is a really simple method which uses [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to concatenate your TXT files and output to a single TXT file, using [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

df = pd.DataFrame()
files = glob('./addr_files/*.txt')

for f in files:
    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=1, skipfooter=1, engine='python'))

df.to_csv('./addr_files/output.txt', index=False)
```

#### Output:

```
(py35) ~/Desktop/so/addr_files
$ cat output.txt
Name,address,zipcode
Rick,ABC,123
Tom,XYZ,456
Jerry,ABC,123
Harry,XYZ,456
John,ABC,123
Mike,XYZ,456
```

## Using GNU `sed`:

Here is another option which will stream the output of each file named `file*.txt` into a new file (`all.txt`), skipping the rows you want to miss; specifically the 1st, 2nd and last.

Given your files are so large, you might want to add a couple `printf` statements for debugging, so you can see the which file is being processed, as the script loops the files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Print the header to the output file.
sed -n 2p file1.txt > all.txt

# Stream (specific) content of all files to output file.
for f in $( ls file*.txt ); do sed '1d;2d;$d' $f >> all.txt; done
```

#### Output:

```
(base) user@host ~/Desktop/so/concat                                                                             
$ cat all.txt
Name,address,zipcode
Rick,ABC,123
Tom,XYZ,456
Jerry,ABC,123
Harry,XYZ,456
John,ABC,123
Mike,XYZ,456
```

Comment: Thanks,this works but to concatenate four 5 GB files it takes over an hour to complete.

Comment: Hmm.  Are you on Linux?  Can look into sed and see if we can stream each file into a single file that way.  Please update your question with an exact header and footer record, so we know how to build the regex.

Comment: Alternatively ... rather than storing in a CSV file, why don’t we put your data into a proper **database**; which is **designed to handle data of this size**.

Comment: My solution demands to concatenate the file, not to load into tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1)You can modify a little what you had done in the following:

```
filenames = ['File1.txt', 'File2.txt', 'file3.txt']
with open('output_file', 'w') as outfile:
    outille.write("Name,address,zipcode\n")
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                if line.find("Trailer record") < 0 and line.find("Name,address,zipcode") < 0 :
                    outfile.write(line)
```

2) Alternatively if you are familiar with grep command in unix you can use it. You can use it directly in Python with the sh library and chaining the commands.

Answer (score 0):

#### The python way

Concatenate iterators so you don't have problems with huge files.

```
import os
import fnmatch
from itertools import filterfalse
import csv

def get_files(pattern, path):
    """
    Get all files from path that match pattern
    """
    for path, _, filelist in os.walk(path):
        for name in fnmatch.filter(filelist, pattern):
                yield os.path.join(path, name)

def open_files(filenames):
    """
    Open all files that match pattern
    """
    for filename in filenames:
        file = open(filename, newline="")
        yield file
        file.close()

def get_csv(files):
    """
    Return csv reader for files
    """
    for file in files:
        lines = filterfalse(lambda line: line.startswith("H,") or line.startswith("T,"), file)
        reader = csv.DictReader(lines, delimiter=",")
        yield reader

def concatenate(iterators):
    """
    Concatenate iterators into a single sequence
    """
    for it in iterators:
        yield from it

with open('output.txt', 'w', newline="") as output:
    filenames = get_files('*.txt', '.')
    files = open_files(filenames)
    csvs = get_csv(files)
    lines = concatenate(csvs)
    
    fieldnames = ["Name","address","zipcode"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in lines:
        writer.writerow(line)
```